# How to call the root class methods of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, super

```
class Animal{
  constructor(){...}
  walk(){ console.log('Animal walking...')}
}

class Mammal extends Animal{
  constructor(){...}
   walk(){console.log('Mammal walking...')}
}

class Cat extends Mammal{
  constructor(){}
  walk(){console.log('Cat walking...')}
}
```

In the above class hierarchy, I would like to call the Animal's **walk()** implementation from a **Cat** object

I tried :

```
class Cat extends Mammal{
  constructor(){}
  walk(){
     super.super.walk()
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'walk' of undefined

Comment: You could try -> `Animal.prototype.walk.call(c)`

Comment: `Animal.prototype.walk()` and if you want to call it in the context of the child class `Animal.prototype.walk.call(c)`

Comment: @Keith , taha : That worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling **Animal's** walk() method from **Cat**, *bypassing Mammal's walk()*:

```
class Cat extends Mammal{
  walk(){
     Animal.prototype.walk.call(this)
  }
}
```

Suggested by [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870228/keith) and [taha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6787455/taha)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `super` from outside an instance, only from inside the class that's doing the inheriting.

```
class Cat extends Mammal {
  walk() {
    super.walk()
  }
}
```

If you want to call the `Animal` class' `walk()` method from your `Cat` class,  don't override it in your `Mammal` class. This will allow `Mammal` to inherit the `walk()` from `Animal`.

```
class Animal {
  walk() { console.log('Animal walking...') }
}

class Mammal extends Animal {
   // don't override walk if you don't have to
}

class Cat extends Mammal {
  walk() {
    super.walk() // will print 'Animals walking...'
  }
}
```

Comment: This calls Mammal's walk() method. I want to bypass that and call Animal's walk() method. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Naveen I've updated my answer to explain super chaining, but you really shouldn't have to do this with proper OOP inheritance.

Comment: Actually, Mammal's walk() method prints "Mammal walking.." if I do super.walk() it prints "Animal walking... Mammel walking..". I just want "Animal walking..." to be printed. super.super.walk() says **Cannot read property 'walk' of undefined**

Comment: @Naveen I've updated the answer again based on what you've told me.